# setContentView throws NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, class, nullpointerexception, setcontentview

I have an MainActivity and an extended DsiplayClass. Out of this DisplayClass I wanted to change the ContentView via setContentView, but all I got is an NullPointerException.

Please help me and tell me why.

**MainActivity:**

```
public class Main extends Activity {

    DisplayClass display;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        display = new DisplayClass();

        display.showMain();
    }

}
```

**DisplayClass:**

```
public class DisplayClass extends Main {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    public void DisplayClass() {

    }

    public void showMain() {
        setContentView(R.layout.mainmenu);
    }

}
```

NullPointerException is caused in the line where I set the "setContentView(R.layout.mainmenu);" and in this line "display.showMain();".

Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What exactly are you trying to do here? You should put your `setContentView(R.layout.mainmenu);` in your `Main` class' `onCreate()` method. Delete `DisplayClass` completely.

The reason why you are getting a null pointer is because that `Activity`, (`DisplayClass`), hasn't actually been "started."

```
public class DisplayClass {
    public static showMain(Activity main) {
        main.setContentView(R.id.layoutmain);
    }
}
```

And then inside the `onCreate` method in your `Main` `Activity`...

```
DisplayClass.showMain(this);
```

Comment: Wanted to clean up my code. Put all together whats has anything to do with displaying something.
Excuse my insufficient English skills, please.

Comment: I wouldn't suggest that, good sir. But, if you really have some reason to do that, you should not have `DisplayClass` extend `Main`. Instead, you should just create a regular class, and then have the static method... `setMain(Activity main)` and in the method you would call `main.setContentView(R.layout.mainmenu)`.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!!!
Currently iam a beginner in Java. Thanks for your help and your patience.